# pass values from a textfield of a form to php using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

What i have in mind is an alert box that greets the user of a name that is specified in the textfield after pressing the button

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


  $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

     $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
     }); 

     dataString = $("#testform").serialize();

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    }
      }); 
  });


});
</script>
</head>


<body>
  <form id="testform">
    <input type="text" name="jeds" value="jed" id="jedid">
  </form>    
  <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">    
</body>
```

**test.php**

```
    <?PHP
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        print "hello " . $name;
        }
    ?>
```

im not sure why it can't catch the name.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Are you getting an error message? A popup but no name?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);` to learn more. This will help you to understand which data is posted from the client side to your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<form id="testform">
<input type="text" name="jeds" value="jed" id="jedid">
</form>

<input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
```

to

```
<form id="testform" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="jeds" value="jed" id="jedid">
    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    print "hello " . $name;
}
```

to

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $name = $_POST['jeds'];
    print "hello " . $name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="jeds" value="jed" id="jedid">
```

should be

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="jed" id="jedid">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not mentioned the method in the form tag(by default it is GET). you are requesting the variable from $_POST. give method name as post